# How to remove duplicates based on text similarity across rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I have a dataset of news headlines. I'd like to remove duplicate or highly similar headlines based on textual similarity with headlines of the past ten days. For highly similar headlines, I want to keep the earliest. For example, I will keep `"SECTION:BUSINESS; Business; Events; Pg.2"` for only the `2014-08-04` one.

I'm thinking doing a join based on Date and Headline where the date is within the last ten days, something like this(in SQL statement):

```
create table df_joined as 
select a.*, b.date as date_b, b.Headline as Headline_b from 
df a inner join df[["Date", "Headline"]] b on a.date - b.date <= 10
```

Next, I can calculate the similarity measure:

```
df_joined["Similarity"] = similar_function (df_joined.Headline, df_joined.Headline_b)
```

Then, for each group of `(date, headline)`, if any row has a similarity higher than the chosen benchmark, I drop the entire group. Finally, I collapse the groups.

Not sure how to do this in Pandas. Thank you!

[image: Sample Data]
he

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the function pandas.Series.unique? It returns an array with no duplicates, and can handle strings.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html